# DJango displaying incorrect view

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying my best to learn Django for the past few days, and I came across an unusual problem. I know this is very basic form some, so I'm asking for your help on this one.

I created two different views that will show two different outputs.

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.template import loader
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    
    # Create your views here.
    def computers(request):
        template_name = loader.get_template('computers/computers.html')
        context = {
            'a':[
                {
                    'sample1': 'WMCD0001',
                    'sample2': 'Desktop',
                    'sample3': 'Lenovo ThinkPad',
                    'sample4': '10.10.10.100',
                    'sample5': 'Active',
                },
            ]
        }
        return HttpResponse(template_name.render(context, request))
    
    def newdevice(request):
        return render(request, 'computers/newdevice.html')
        # return HttpResponse(template.render(request, context))
```

I also configured the urls file on the app which goes like this

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        # path('', views.index, name='computers'),
        path('', views.computers, name='computers'),
        path('computers/newdevice/', views.newdevice, name='computers/newdevice')
    ]
```

The last this I wrote was the urls in the project which is like this

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include, path
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('computers/', include('computers.urls')),
        path('computers/newdevice/', include('computers.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

When I try to go to the localhost:8000/computers, it shows the correct view. The problem is when I try to view the page under localhost:8000/computers/newdevice it shows the same view as the one in computers.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for those who will help

Comment: please provide code not img

Comment: Hi, are you unable to see the image?

Comment: According to stackoverflow rule, you must share with code not code as img otherwise you will get downvotes on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple thing, you don't need to include computer urls multiple times because of this multiple includes for computer urls you are getting same view. Just delete that second include.

Delete this:

```
path('computers/newdevice/', include('computers.urls')),
```

And keep only this:

```
path('computers/', include('computers.urls')),
```

And now navigate to below route:

```
localhost:8000/computers/
 
localhost:8000/computers/computers/newdevice/
```

**OR:**

Change this:

```
path('computers/newdevice/',views.newdevice)
```

To this:

```
path('newdevice/',views.newdevice)
```

And navigate to below routes:

```
 localhost:8000/computers/newdevice/
```

And now you will get the correct output